# Text fill effect - simulate a block of color passing through text

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to create a text effect so when you hover over text, a block of color seems to pass through the text.

I followed exactly what [the first example here](https://tympanus.net/Development/TextStylesHoverEffects/) (for the word "Kukuri") does by using a `:before` pseudo-element to achieve the color fill. I have the code written here in SCSS:

```
.text {
  position: relative;

  &:hover { 
    &:before {
      width: 100%;
    }
  } 

  &:before {
    content: 'HELLO'; // if our text was "HELLO"
    width: 0%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: red;
    transition: width 350ms ease-in-out;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 0%;
  }
}
```

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to animate the `:before` element's width the other way? So once it hits 100% width and fills with color, then the left side starts emptying and it goes back to 0% fill.

The end goal is to use this for a navigation menu. Something like this effect where it seems like a block of color is moving through menu items when you hover:

[image]

For something like this, hovering over "About" item would make the fill color wipe down while

#### Attempted Solutions

1. I tried translating the `:before` element, changing the `left` and `right` properties, and changing `transform-origin` to no avail.
2. I've tried looking into `mix-blend-mode` to try and create a rectangular mask that could potentially add color to the text. However, to my understanding, `mix-blend-mode` only works with text and not with rectangular divs with background-colors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use blend modes for this effect, here you have one posibility:

I opted for moving the background of the pseudo rather than moving the pseudo itself, This way you won't have side effects when the pseudo is over other elements.

Also, it isn't clear for me if you want a single slide or a double one. I have set it to be a double one ( from black to red and again to black. You can change this easily adjusting the final background position

```css
.demo {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.demo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, transparent 25%, red 25%, red 75%, transparent 75% );
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    background-size: 400% 100%;
    transition: background-position 2s linear;
    background-position: 100% 0%;
}

.demo:hover:after {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">TEST1</div>
<div class="demo">TEST2</div>
```

To change the movement to vertical, you need to change

- the gradient direction
- which of the image dimensions is oversized
- the background position that is changed on hover

```css
.demo {
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    position: relative;
}

.demo:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, transparent 25%, red 25%, red 75%, transparent 75% );
    mix-blend-mode: lighten;
    background-size: 100% 400%;   /* changed vertical dimension */
    transition: background-position 2s linear;
    background-position: 0% 100%; /* changed 100 position to vertical*/
}

.demo:hover:after {
    background-position: 0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">TEST1</div>
<div class="demo">TEST2</div>
```

Comment: yes this one is good too but you said it fits more the OP, why ? :) .. maybe i didn't understand something in the question, as i don't really see a visual difference with both our solution.

Comment: If i understand question correctly, move/effect should be vertical, from bottom to the top (not left to right side), and vice versa?

Comment: @sinisake yes it should be like that but the last part made it a bit confusion as he talked about left/right. By the way it should be easy to change direction ;)

Comment: @TemaniAfif I think that the OP didn't want a separate element in the HTML to make this effect, in the question it says something about using a pseudo. Otherwise, the net result is equivalent.

Comment: @sinisake The images show a vertical movement, but the example linked, the SCCS code and the final comment are all about an horizontal movement. Anyway, as TemaniAfif says, it's easy to adapt the movement direction

Comment: Thank you and @TemaniAfif for your very detailed answers! I ended up going with this solution because I liked how it only moved the pseudo element and not the element's background. Both answers were great though and I'm sorry the question was a bit vague.

Comment: @vals for this specific example, to achieve vertical movement, I ended up having to animate the "top" property of the pseudo-element. For some reason, flipping the background-position properties didn't work for me so if you have time, would you mind sharing an example of the vertical movement?

Comment: Happy that it helped you ! I have added a second snippet, explaining the changes required

Answer (score 2):

You may do something like this by simply using a layer that pass above your element with transparent background:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
}

ul li:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
  transition: 2s;
  z-index: 2;
}

ul.ver li:before {
  top: 0;
  left: -100%;
}

ul.hor li:before {
  top: -100%;
  left: 0;
}

ul.ver li:hover::before {
  left: 100%;
}

ul.ver.half li:hover::before {
  left: 0;
}

ul.hor li:hover::before {
  top: 100%;
}
ul.hor.half li:hover::before {
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
<ul class="hor">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
<ul class="ver half">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
<ul class="hor half">
  <li>Home</li>
  <li>About</li>
</ul>
```

And here is another example using `mix-blend-mode` with text:

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, red, red);
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-weight: bold;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: 1s;
}
ul.hor li {
  background-position: 0% 200%;
}
ul.ver li {
  background-position: 200% 0%;
}

ul li span {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  background-color: white;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}

ul.hor li:hover {
  background-position: 0% -100%;
}
ul.ver li:hover {
  background-position:-100% 0%;
}
ul.hor.half li:hover {
  background-position: 0% 0%;
}
ul.ver.half li:hover {
  background-position:0% 0%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="hor">
  <li><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><span>About</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="ver">
  <li><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><span>About</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="hor half">
  <li><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><span>About</span></li>
</ul>
<ul class="ver half">
  <li><span>Home</span></li>
  <li><span>About</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nice answer. I just added another one to show how to do it using pseudo elements, because I think it fits more what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

```
    .text {
 text-transform: uppercase;
 font-weight: 900;
 overflow: hidden;
 line-height: 0.75;
 color: #c5c2b8;
    position:relative;
}
    .text:before {
     content: attr(data-letters);
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
     overflow: hidden;
     color: red;
     white-space: nowrap;
     width: 0%;
        top:0;
     -webkit-transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
     transition: width 0.4s 0.3s;
    }

    .text:hover:before {
     width: 100%;
    }
    <span class="text" href="#" data-letters="hello">hello</span>
```